# How do I give functionality to a MenuBarItem in a .NET maui app?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I created a menu like this:

```xml
<ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Passwords">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Move"/>
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Groups">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Rename"/>
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Tools">
        <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Password Viewing">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Create Password"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Lock Password Viewing"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Change Password"/>
        </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
        <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Password Database">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Create New Database"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Change Current Database"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Change Password"/>
        </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
    </MenuBarItem>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Exit" />
</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
```

But now I want to give a `MenuBarItem` a function when clicked on. For instance, how would I close the form when a user clicks on the exit `MenuBarItem`?

I tried

```
<MenuBarItem Text="Exit" Clicked="Exit_click" />
```

but I keep getting the message:

> The property 'Clicked' was not found in type 'MenuBarItem'

Is there another way?

Comment: AFAIK only `MenuFlyoutItem` supports that kind of behavior. You can bind a `Command` from your ViewModel to a `MenuFlyoutItem` as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menu-bar).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/commanding), but only on `MenuFlyoutItem` instances, AFAIK:

```xml
<ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
    <MenuBarItem Text="Passwords">
        <MenuFlyoutItem
           Text="New"
           Command="{Binding NewPasswordCommmand}" />
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Move"/>
    </MenuBarItem>
</ContentPage.MenuBarItems>
```

And in your ViewModel you'll have various Commands to bind to, e.g.:

```cs
// Creates a Command with the name NewPasswordCommand
[RelayCommand]
private void NewPassword()
{
    //Do something here...
}
```

In case that you don't use the MVVM Source Generators (c.f. `[RelayCommand]`), you can also use a classic implementation:

```cs
private ICommand _newPasswordCommand;
public ICommand NewPasswordCommand => _newPasswordCommand ??= new Command(NewPassword);

private void NewPassword()
{
   //Do something here...
}
```